# NotDirectoryException while acessing a JAR file

Tags: java, jar, filesystems

Good evening,

I'm trying to access a JAR File dynamically that contains a couple of *.class files.
I've read about it, and a good way is to use the java class FileSystem to access several files inside the jar. I've wrote the following code:

```
private void loadJar(String gameName) {
        final String packageBinaryName = gameName;
        final String pathname = packageBinaryName.replace(".", "/") +".jar";
        URI uri = null;
        uri = new File(pathname).toURI();//.toURL();
        final String[] array = uri.toString().split("!");
        FileSystem fs = null;
        Path dir;

        try 
        {
            if(array.length == 2) 
            {
                final Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
                fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create(array[0]), env);
                dir = fs.getPath(array[1]);   
            } 
            else
                dir = Paths.get(uri);

            DirectoryStream<Path> stream;

            System.out.println(dir);
            stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.class");
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

But I get a java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException

The JAR File exists and it points to the write path. What may be causing this problem?

The dir prints the following:

```
C:\Users\afonso\workspace\GameEvaluatorDummy\src\TicTacToe.jar
```

EDIT: Note that debugging the dir statement gets its value on the else statement

```
dir=Paths.get(uri);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it gets to the else path.
The URI you are checking will never contain an exclamation mark.
But simply be the URI to the JAR file.
Except you give as parameter to this method something with exclamation mark, but this wouldn't work either I'd say.

What you are after is

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(new URI("jar:file:///path/to/the.jar"), Collections.<String,?>emptyMap());
Path dir = fs.getPath("/");
Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.class*);
```

But be aware that this does not automatically recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: You're right about the excalmation mark but that makes difference about the error that occures accessing the JAR?

Comment: Well, a JAR file is a file, not a directory.

Comment: Maybe it works if you give it a jar-URL to Paths.get() instead. `jar:path/to/jar!/` if I have it in mind correctly.

Comment: you mean something like this? "jar:"+pathname+"!/" ?

Comment: You sir are a trully gentleman! Thank you for your help. I've learned a great leason today